# Magento - DownloadController.php get Order ID

Tags: php, magento, download, product

In the DownloadController.php I have created a module to override the linkAction()

I needed to get the product SKU and Order ID which the product corresponds to. I have been able to get the SKU but I don't know how to get the Order ID in this function.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're within the `link` action, you can use this :

```
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($linkPurchasedItem->getOrderItemId());
// Use $orderItem->getOrderId() to get order ID
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The code is working and I'm getting a value such as '84'. Is there anyway to get the long digit code which shows on the front end such as '100000098'.

Comment: Yes, with `$orderItem->getOrder()->getIncrementId()`